# Spring Boot JPA Many to Many Join Table Exception

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, many-to-many

I tried many JPA many to many examples but none of them works, this is what I have to use join table to implement the many to many model:

its running on 3.0.9 spring boot framework

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.9'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.2'
}

group = 'com.zousysko'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'
    runtimeOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2022.0.3")
}
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}
```

Movie.java

```
@Table(name = "movies")
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Movie {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 150)
    private String name;

    @Lob
    private String description;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer releaseDate;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "movies")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

}
```

User.java

```
@Table(name = "users")
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String email;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_movies",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id")
    )
    private Set<Movie> movies = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Repositories

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
}

public interface MovieRepository extends CrudRepository<Movie, Integer> {
}
```

Run it:

```
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner loadData(UserRepository userRepository, MovieRepository movieRepository) {
        return args -> {
            Movie movie1 = Movie.builder().name("Movie 1").description("Movie 1 description").releaseDate(2010).build();
            Movie movie2 = Movie.builder().name("Movie 2").description("Movie 2 description").releaseDate(2020).build();
            Movie createdMovie1 = movieRepository.save(movie1);
            Movie createdMovie2 = movieRepository.save(movie2);
            User user = User.builder().email("user@email.com").name("John Doe").build();
            user.getMovies().add(createdMovie1);
            user.getMovies().add(createdMovie2);
            User createdUser = userRepository.save(user);
        };
    }
```

When I start the SpringBoot application, it throws exception of:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'user-service.users_movies' doesn't exist
```

I was kept got this error, any fixes?

This is the log:

```
2023-09-05T21:27:20.389+08:00  INFO 5395 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-09-05T21:27:21.159+08:00  INFO 5395 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@78eafad
2023-09-05T21:27:21.165+08:00  INFO 5395 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-09-05T21:27:21.254+08:00  INFO 5395 --- [           main] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Hibernate: 
    
    alter table users_movies 
       drop 
       foreign key FKt4hasm7tvj0vor58ql33xptjy
2023-09-05T21:27:23.098+08:00  WARN 5395 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    alter table users_movies 
       drop 
       foreign key FKt4hasm7tvj0vor58ql33xptjy" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    alter table users_movies 
       drop 
       foreign key FKt4hasm7tvj0vor58ql33xptjy" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:419) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:403) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applyConstraintDropping(SchemaDropperImpl.java:373) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:256) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:117) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:242) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:415) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1423) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1155) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at com.zousysko.UserApplication.main(UserApplication.java:20) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'user-service.users_movies' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:121) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:763) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'user-service.users_movies' doesn't exist

    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    ... 37 common frames omitted

Hibernate: 
    
    alter table users_movies 
       drop 
       foreign key FKhhj9vi206o88q0typfntk3fek
2023-09-05T21:27:23.118+08:00  WARN 5395 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    alter table users_movies 
       drop 
       foreign key FKhhj9vi206o88q0typfntk3fek" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    alter table users_movies 
       drop 
       foreign key FKhhj9vi206o88q0typfntk3fek" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:419) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:403) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applyConstraintDropping(SchemaDropperImpl.java:373) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:256) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:117) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:242) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:415) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1423) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1155) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at com.zousysko.UserApplication.main(UserApplication.java:20) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'user-service.users_movies' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:121) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:763) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    ... 37 common frames omitted

Hibernate: 
    
    drop table if exists movies
Hibernate: 
    
    drop table if exists movies_seq
Hibernate: 
    
    drop table if exists users
Hibernate: 
    
    drop table if exists users_movies
Hibernate: 
    
    drop table if exists users_seq
Hibernate: 
    
    create table movies (
       id integer not null,
        description tinytext,
        name varchar(150) not null,
        release_date integer not null,
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: 
    
    create table movies_seq (
       next_val bigint
    ) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: 
    
    insert into movies_seq values ( 1 )
Hibernate: 
    
    create table users (
       id integer not null,
        email varchar(100) not null,
        name varchar(100) not null,
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: 
    
    create table users_movies (
       user_id integer not null,
        movie_id integer not null,
        primary key (user_id, movie_id)
    ) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: 
    
    create table users_seq (
       next_val bigint
    ) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: 
    
    insert into users_seq values ( 1 )
Hibernate: 
    
    alter table users 
       add constraint UK_6dotkott2kjsp8vw4d0m25fb7 unique (email)
Hibernate: 
    
    alter table users 
       add constraint UK_3g1j96g94xpk3lpxl2qbl985x unique (name)
Hibernate: 
    
    alter table users_movies 
       add constraint FKt4hasm7tvj0vor58ql33xptjy 
       foreign key (movie_id) 
       references movies (id)
Hibernate: 
    
    alter table users_movies 
       add constraint FKhhj9vi206o88q0typfntk3fek 
       foreign key (user_id) 
       references users (id)
2023-09-05T21:27:23.545+08:00  INFO 5395 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-09-05T21:27:23.568+08:00  INFO 5395 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-09-05T21:27:24.234+08:00  WARN 5395 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-09-05T21:27:24.930+08:00  INFO 5395 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8077 (http) with context path ''
2023-09-05T21:27:24.942+08:00  INFO 5395 --- [           main] com.zousysko.UserApplication             : Started UserApplication in 10.429 seconds (process running for 12.753)
2023-09-05T21:27:24.949+08:00  INFO 5395 --- [           main] com.zousysko.UserApplication             : hello!!
Hibernate: 
    select
        next_val as id_val 
    from
        movies_seq for update
Hibernate: 
    update
        movies_seq 
    set
        next_val= ? 
    where
        next_val=?
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        movies
        (description, name, release_date, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    select
        next_val as id_val 
    from
        movies_seq for update
Hibernate: 
    update
        movies_seq 
    set
        next_val= ? 
    where
        next_val=?
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        movies
        (description, name, release_date, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?)

> Task :JPA:UserApplication.main() FAILED

Execution failed for task ':JPA:UserApplication.main()'.
> Process 'command '/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 255
```

Comment: What you are showing is being logged as a warning, not error, and is due to running drop table commands (in a drop+create DDL option specified somewhere you aren't showing) against a clean database. They are just warnings and should be expected. If you check the logs, you can see it is creating that table later on - so it will exist when your application is running- and it is executing your loadData and even writing out 'hello!!' to the logs

Comment: It was fixed and I even don't know how after a series of refactoring. My impression is the JPA code and configuration is super sensitive, and the log won't provide the clear direction. Thank you.